# Enable virtualization for esxi server running in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, bios

I have a project that requires me to create an esxi server within VirtualBox. Upon creation of the esxi server, i seem to run into the error below when i try to power on a newly created VM within the esxi.

Any idea how to get around this? The VirtualBox infrastructure is running on 2014 macbook pro which supports virtualization.

[image: Sreenshot]

Comment: Does `sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features` show VMX listed?

Comment: Yes it does list VMX

Comment: I am using Fusion as a client to connect to the esxi server which was created on VirtualBox. My understanding is that vsphere only works on windows

Comment: In the `.vmx` file of the ESXi virtual machine manually add this line `vhv.enable = "TRUE"` to enable nested VT.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately adding that line to the .vmx file and rebooting the VM doesnt resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled VT-x option
That's under System > Acceleration > Hardware virtualization